# How to customize the way your site appears in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I noticed that when you embed sites like Youtube.com and Streamble.com, only the video appears in the iframe. How do they do that? Shouldn't an iframe load the whole webpage?

**What I've tried:**
Initially I thought you're supposed to wrap the mp4 file in og:video tags, but that didn't work.

Comment: Please make more specific questions with example code and details on your error so that we can help you figure out what your problem is.

Comment: I don't know what more information you need....my question is very simple. How does Youtube ensure that only the video is shown in the iFrame, and not the whole webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do they do that?  By only serving up the video.  Look at the url in the `src` attribute on the iframe.  Load it up on a browser (you'll need to add http to the front of it) and you'll get only the video content.

Comment: But then how about this for example

https://streamable.com/h9lbq

I tried using an iframe on that site and it only rendered the video:

https://jsfiddle.net/dk2m3471/

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right.  Check out the url of the `src` in that iframe.  It's just the video too: https://streamable.com/res/h9lbq

Comment: ah okay gotcha. thanks brotha. I was asking because if you're familiar with reddit.com, they let you post a streamable link (https://streamable.com/h9lbq) and it automatically renders an iframe for it so you can watch the video in reddit. Is that something reddit controls - where if you post a streamable link it changes https://streamable.com/h9lbq to https://streamable.com/res/h9lbq?

Comment: I have no idea about how Reddit works.  But I do know how SO works... if this answers your question, please accept it. ;)